# Crash when calling ReadFile after LockFileEx

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I have several processes that try to read and write the same file. I want each of them to lock the file so that only one of them accesses it at a time.

I tried this (**edit: this is a complete test code this time**):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Windows.h"


bool test()
{
        const char* path = "test.txt";

        HANDLE hFile = CreateFileA(path,
                        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
                        FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
                        NULL,
                        OPEN_ALWAYS,
                        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                        NULL);

        if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        {
                printf("ERROR: Cannot open file %s\n", path);
                return false;
        }

        // Lock the file
        {
                OVERLAPPED overlapped = {0};
                BOOL res = LockFileEx(hFile, LOCKFILE_EXCLUSIVE_LOCK, 0, ~0, ~0, &overlapped);
                if (!res)
                {
                        printf("ERROR: Cannot lock file %s\n", path);
                        return false;
                }
        }

        DWORD fileSize = GetFileSize(hFile, NULL);
        if (fileSize > 0)
        {
                char* content = new char[fileSize+1];

                // Read the file
                BOOL res = ReadFile(hFile, content, fileSize, NULL, NULL);
                if (!res)
                {
                        printf("ERROR: Cannot read file %s\n", path);
                }

                delete[] content;
        }


        const char* newContent = "bla";
        int newContentSize = 3;

        // Write the file
        BOOL res = WriteFile(hFile, newContent, newContentSize, NULL, NULL);
        if (!res)
        {
                //int err = GetLastError();
                printf("ERROR: Cannot write to file\n");
        }

        // Unlock the file
        {
                OVERLAPPED overlapped = {0};
                UnlockFileEx(hFile, 0, ~0, ~0, &overlapped);
        }

        CloseHandle(hFile);

        return true;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
        bool res = test();

        return 0;
}
```

This works fine on my computer, which has Windows 8. But on my colleague's computer, which has Windows 7, it crashes. Specifically, the calls to ReadFile and WriteFile crash, always.

**Note that it never enters the code paths with the error printfs. This code triggers no error except for a *write at location 0x00000000* in ReadFile (when run on Windows 7).**

We tried to also pass the overlapped struct to the ReadFile and WriteFile calls. It prevents the crash but the lock doesn't work anymore, the file is all scrambled (not with this test code, with the real code).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not checking the return results and GetLastError().

Comment: Include complete code and be specific. It crashes on `ReadFile` or `WriteFile`? It can't crash on both.

Comment: @RichardCritten I didn't include it here, but I do check return results. On Windows 8, there is no error. I'm checking again on Window 7 to be sure.

Comment: @Rohan If I comment the call to ReadFile, it crashes in WriteFile. I'll try to make a minimal repro code.

Comment: "Crashes" is not a suitable error description. Also, as Richard suggested, check `GetLastError()` after failed calls if the documentation for the function suggests that you need to.

Comment: What does the documentation say about the lifetime of the OVERLAPPED structure that is passed to some calls? Does it have to exist after the call? Also, what are those `~0` magic numbers? I believe there are a bunch of macros/constants that should be put there instead.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt, there is no error. All functions return success and GetLastError returns only 0 or 183 (file already exist).

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt ~ is the not operator, ~0 is like unsigned -1. It's equal to MAXDWORD and using this macro instead makes no difference.

Comment: `const char* newContent = "bla";
int newContentSize = sizeof(newContent);` `sizeof(newContent)` is wrong, it will return the size of the pointer NOT the length of string "bla".

Comment: @RichardCritten COME ON! That's not the problem!

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I didn't see anything in the doc about the lifetime of overlapped. It's full of 0 anyway and giving the same address to both LockFileEx and UnlockFile doesn't change anything. Good idea though.

Comment: using macros instead of constants makes a _BIG_ difference - not mathematically but programmatically, your application may (!) be able to run indefinitely with different windows patches / versions whereas constant values _will_ make it crash at some time in the future --- because the expected value has changed and an appropriate macro would've resolved to the correct one. Methinks you should'nt dive into WINAPI this early in your learning-curve .... you'd be better off with programming practises for now. There is a (lots of, actually) reason for  people preaching about macros, you now ...

Comment: Right. I'll do that then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like your problem is:

lpNumberOfBytesRead [out, optional]  argument is null in your call.

**This parameter can be NULL only when the lpOverlapped parameter is *not* NULL.**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365467%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's what I missed! It also explains why it worked when adding the overalapped parameter.

Answer (score -2):

Heres your problem :

You are missing a necessary struct-member **and**:

`0` and `~0` and `{0}` are all **bad code**, constant expressions like these will always produce unepected results -- WINAPI doesnt work like libc, **parameters are not always compared against constants**, instead they are tested against/via macros and other preprocessor-definitions themselves so **passing constant values or initializing WINAPI structs with constants will often lead to errors like these**.

After years of experimenting i have found that there is only one surefire way of avoiding them, i will express it in corrected code :

```
OVERLAPPED overlapped;
overlapped.hEvent = CreateEvent( ........... ); // put valid parameters here!
UnlockFileEx(hFile, 0 /*"reserved"*/, ULONG_MAX, ULONG_MAX, &overlapped);
```

please read this carefully : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365716%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Well, the documentation actually says that I should initialize members to 0. And for hEvent it says specifically: _You must initialize the hEvent member to a valid handle or zero_.
I'll try your method because I have no other idea, but I'm not trying to do asynchronous I/O so I'm not sure it's going to be relevant.

Comment: try `NULL` instead of zero - and throw away the `{0}`

Comment: .... and since he doesnt write anything i think we can assume his error is resolved :-)

Comment: I was just having lunch. No you solution doesn't work.

Comment: Specifically what is bad about `OVERLAPPED overlapped = {0};`? Would you consider `OVERLAPPED overlapped;` more appropriate? Why?