# Why do I get an access violation when using the ReadFile() function?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have been trying to read from a file and I am using the Windows API function `ReadFile()`. I have used the following code:

```
int main()
{
    LPDWORD bytesRead = 0;
    HANDLE hFile = CreateFile("TestFile.txt", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, 0, OPEN_ALWAYS, 0, 0);

    char Data[600];

    ReadFile(hFile, Data, 10, bytesRead, 0);

    cout << Data;
    cin.get();
}
```

When I execute this code, it throws an access violation!

Why is this? I feel that I am using `ReadFile()` correctly - but I am probably wrong. How can I fix this error (how to use `ReadFile()` properly)?

Comment: You might want to write `char Data[600] = {0};` instead of `char Data[600];`.

Comment: The lack of error checking is also a problem.

Comment: Your `cout << Data;` is buggy. That version of `operator<<` is for C-style strings, not arbitrary data.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Crash when calling ReadFile](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27690258/902497) due to invalid `lpNumberOfBytesRead` parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fourth parameter to `ReadFile` is a pointer to a `DWORD`. You have given it a pointer, but it's null - it doesn't actually point to a `DWORD`.

```
DWORD bytesRead = 0;
...
ReadFile(hFile, Data, 10, &bytesRead, 0);
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks, I'll put it as an answer in 7 minutes because stackoverflow is not allowing me to accept an answer in 3 minutes :)

Answer (score 1):

This might not be your main issue, but you should write:

```
char Data[600] = {0};
```

instead of:

```
char Data[600];
```

The latter statement leaves your array uninitialized. Then, after executing
`ReadFile()`, your string might not be terminated by a `\0` character. In this case `cout` doesn't stop printing after 10 bytes. In the worst case you run into another access violation here.

---

As mentioned in the comments by @DavidHeffernan, the following solution will be more efficient than initializing the whole array:

```
DWORD bytesRead = 0;
ReadFile(hFile, Data, 10, &bytesRead, 0);
Data[bytesRead] = '\0';
```

By using `bytesRead` in the last line, you can ensure that the data is correctly terminated by a `\0` character, even if not all requested 10 bytes are read (for example, because the file is shorter than 10 bytes). However, in your real code, you should also check the return value of `ReadFile()` in order to verify whether reading was successful or not. If it fails, you might want to do some error handling.

Comment: I would not recommend initialising the entire buffer. That would be inefficient. Just write a zero byte after the data that was read.

Comment: Outputting an unterminated string could cause an access violation.

Comment: This still accesses uninitialized data if the file is shorter than 10 bytes.

Comment: @RaymondChen: Thanks for the hint! I improved my answer accordingly.